# In Python3 how can I install botan module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I tried this code to encrypt a file:

```
from cryptoshop import encryptfile
from cryptoshop import decryptfile

result1 = encryptfile(filename="test", passphrase="mypassphrase",algo="srp")
print(result1)
```

But I got this error:

> No module named botan

How can I install botan module?

**MY OS : WINDOWS**

**MY PYTHON VERSION : 3.6.3**

*Please write it step by step.*

PS: I found this in cryptoshop module:

```
try:
    import botan
except:
    print("Please install the last version of Botan crypto library.")
    print("http://botan.randombit.net/#download")
    print("For Linux users, try to find it in your package manager.")
    sys.exit(0)
```

I downloaded but how can I install it?

Comment: Have you tried to Google it? What steps have you tried so far?

Comment: Bir daha bunu çözmeyi denemeyeceğim.

Comment: Hem artık bir kriptografi kütüphanesine ihtiyacım yok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the you've already downloaded the botan module, a simple solution would be to unzip the file (if it is zipped) and put it in the same folder as where the cryptoshop module is located. This should allow cryptoshop to use botan.